# Is there a 'correct' pattern for Anglicans and/or Roman Catholics when crossing yourself?

Tags: anglicanism, catholic-catechism, catechumenate, sign-of-the-cross

Some Anglicans 'cross themselves' at various points of an Anglican church service. It is common practice for Roman Catholics. Is there in standard Roman Catholic or Anglican catachesis / instruction any guidance as to a 'correct' motion when crossing yourself:

- left-to-right or right-to-left, for example?
- the horizontal motion first, or the vertical?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### For Catholics, [it's using the right hand, forehead-chest-left shoulder-right shoulder.](http://catechesis-a-journey.blogspot.com/2012/09/the-sign-of-cross.html)

> [The Sign of the Cross](http://www.catholictradition.org/Classics/signum-crucis.htm)  (from the Fountain of Catholic Knowledge,
>   OFFICE OF CATHOLIC PUBLICATIONS, Imprimatur, 1877; and from THE
>   CATECHIST, by the Very Rev. Canon Howe, Imprimatur, 1898)
>
> MAKING THE SIGN OF THE CROSS
>
> The Sign of the Cross is a sacramental if we make it with the right
>   hand by touching the forehead (showing our belief in the Cross), the
>   breast (showing our love of the Cross), and the shoulders (showing our
>   readiness to bear the Cross). Sometimes a triple Cross is made with
>   the thumb for example at the reading of the Gospel. It is made on the
>   forehead, on the heart, and on the lips in order to show our readiness
>   to profess the Cross.

[See also the Baltimore Catechism (1064).](http://www.baltimore-catechism.com/lesson27.htm)

> Q. 1064. How do we make the sign of the cross?
>
> A. We make the sign of the cross by putting the right hand to the
>   forehead, then on the breast, and then to the left and right
>   shoulders, saying, "In the name of the Father, and of the Son, and of
>   the Holy Ghost, Amen."

It is worth noting that the sign of the cross (for a Catholic) is a *sacramental*<sup>1</sup>.

#### That isn't how it was always done

The above sequence is comparatively new.  The previous tradition had lasted for over a thousand years.

> [The early Church Fathers attested to the use of the sign of the cross](http://catholicstraightanswers.com/what-is-the-origin-of-the-sign-of-the-cross/).
>   Tertullian ((De corona, 30, ~ A.D 250) described the commonness of the
>   sign of the cross:  “In all our travels and movements, in all our
>   coming in and going out, in putting on our shoes, at the bath, at the
>   table, in lighting our candles, in lying down, in sitting down,
>   whatever employment occupies us, we mark our foreheads with the sign
>   of the cross”

As described by Pope Innocent III<sup>2</sup> it includes an explanation as to what each motion signifies.  This is how the Greek Orthodox still do it: head, breast, right shoulder, left shoulder.

[D.D. Emmons offers an explanation](http://www.catholicdigest.com/articles/faith/praying/2010/08-24/making-the-sign-of-the-cross)

> For more than 1,200 years most Catholics made the Sign of the Cross in
>   a like manner — that is, people in the Eastern and Western Church
>   touched their forehead, their breast, and their shoulders, going right
>   to left, with three fingers. Before he became pope, Innocent III wrote
>   in The Sacred Mystery of the Altar, *“The Sign of the Cross is made
>   with three fingers, because it is imprinted under invocation of the
>   Trinity… so that it descends from the upper part to the lower, and
>   crosses over from the **right hand to the left because Christ came down
>   from the heaven to the Earth and crossed over from the Jews to the
>   Gentiles.”***
>
> By the end of the Middle Ages, however, Western Catholics were making
>   the Sign of the Cross using the hand in place of the fingers and
>   touching the left shoulder first.  Among the sources documenting this
>   method and the rationale is a 15th-century devotion *used by the nuns
>   of the Brigittine Monastery of Sion in Isleworth, England*, which
>   stated that one should begin with the head and move downward, then to
>   the left side, and then to the right. **The devotion supported this
>   form, saying that Jesus came down from the Father (forehead), was born
>   as man (breast), suffered on the Cross (left shoulder), and ascended
>   into heaven to sit at the right hand of the Father (right shoulder). 
>   This method became the standard in the Western Church.** It is not clear
>   why the changes took place or why they did not also take root in the
>   Eastern Church, which continues using three fingers to make the Sign
>   of the Cross and from right to left.

#### Anglicans are "a Western Church"

[The Anglican confession uses the same form as the Catholics](http://anglicanpastor.com/the-sign-of-the-cross/) (see the origin of this practice, per Emmons).  (The source is a current website article written by an Anglican Pastor, Greg Goebel<sup>3</sup>).

> How do I make the sign?
>
> The hand and finger traces Christ’s cross upon one’s head, heart
>   (center of chest), left shoulder and right shoulder.  In the East it
>   is right, then left shoulder. In some traditions, the finger is kissed
>   after making the sign, or returned to the heart.  When a priest or
>   bishop is blessing the people, he makes the sign as if signing them.
>   This means that rather than signing himself, he moves from their left
>   to their right.

---

> <sup>1</sup>[The characteristics of sacramentals](http://www.vatican.va/archive/ccc_css/archive/catechism/p2s2c4a1.htm)
>
> 1668 Sacramentals are instituted for the sanctification of certain
>   ministries of the Church, certain states of life, a great variety of
>   circumstances in Christian life, and the use of many things helpful to
>   man. ... They always include a prayer, often accompanied by a specific sign, such as the laying on of hands, **the sign of the cross**, or the sprinkling of holy water (which recalls Baptism).
>
> 1670 Sacramentals do not confer the grace of the Holy Spirit in the
>   way that the sacraments do, but by the Church's prayer, they prepare
>   us to receive grace and dispose us to cooperate with it.

<sup>2</sup> (Innocentius III, De sacro altaris mysterio, II, xlv in Patrologia Latina 217, 825C--D.)

<sup>3</sup>  "Greg {Goebel} is the founder of Anglican Pastor and serves as editor and one of the writers. He is an Anglican Priest of the Anglican Church in North America."

Comment: Great answer covering all bases. Please accept my green tick of thanks! :-)

Comment: @EleventhDoctor Good question, I knew the Greeks did it different as my brother married a gal from the Greek Orthodox tradition.  But I had to dig a bit to find when the traditions parted.  That surprised me a bit.

Comment: I do it with my left hand, being left-handed, and no one has ever corrected me. It would feel strange and difficult to make the sign of the cross with my right.

Comment: @MattGutting This is a place where "intentions" (what's in your heart) trump "correct form" issues, for example if someone is missing the right hand or it is injured.  I'd not worry about it.  It's not a dogma.

Comment: I agree that it is not critical to do a sign in a specific way (as @MattGutting says). But I appreciate this answer because I value the beautiful insights into the meaning that the sign has for those who have thought carefully about it.